# Reading bytes from stream, and convert to string

Tags: delphi, tcp, byte, xmldocument, indy10

Im having a problem while reading a stream from a Client. Im using Delphi XE3 with Indy 10.
This Client, send me a tagged text data stream, that is in XML format. My problem start when i read data with a TIdTCPServer. With this code:

```
if Acontext.Connection.IoHandler.InputbufferisEmpty then
begin
 Acontext.Connection.IoHandler.CheckforDataonSource(1000);
 Acontext.Connection.IoHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
 if Acontext.Connection.IoHandler.InputbufferisEmpty then Exit; 
end;
Acontext.Connection.Iohandler.ReadBytes(Abuffer,      
  Acontext.connection.ioHandler.Inputbuffer.size);
data := BytesToString(Abuffer, Tencoding.bigendianUnicode);
```

Data is encoded in BigEndianUnicode. I noticed that when im recieving data, the server read and show me the data in 2 'blocks' diferents. If the server recieve the same data all the time, when i parse with BytesToString the data get "cut" at same char everytime.

Here is a result of what im getting:

```
<rootNode>
  <Node1></Node1>
  <Node2></Node2>
  <
   Node3></Node3>
  <Node4></Node4>
```

The problem get bigger, when i assign that WideString to an XMLDocument. I get an Invalid at the top level of the document error.

Sometimes, i run the server and get all the data correct, without this error, but when i close the aplication and run it again, the server recieve the data corrupted.

Sorry, for my english. I need some help with this.

Comment: Can you post client code? It looks like it's not been flushed.

Comment: Its a 3rd party software, only have the software and some documentation that say the message format and encoding. Nothing more.

Comment: What does the documentation say about the message format?  It is important, as it affects how you code your reading logic.

Comment: The documentation doesnt says anything about how the client sends the message. It only says that is a text data stream that is encoded in Unicode, high-order byte first (BigEndian). This messages are part from a protocol.

Comment: The message may define the encoding used for its text content, but the protocol defines how the message is framed on the TCP connection.  So how is the protocol defined?  How is the message data framed?  Can you provide the actual documentation? Or a capture of the raw TCP data you are trying to read?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the documentation only show how the nodes of the XML message are. It doesnt says anything about the transmission of the message. I will try to get the software documentation.

Comment: It has to say how they are transmitted, otherwise noone would know how to interact with this client.

Answer (score 3):

You are only reading whatever raw bytes happen to be in the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` at the moment you access it, so you are likely not reading the entire XML, or worse you are reading more data that follows the XML.  If the client is sensible, it should be sending either the XML length before the XML data, or a unique terminator after the XML data.  Either of which would allow you to read the entire XML by itself in full without having to resort to calling `CheckforDataOnSource()` at all (which you should be avoiding in most situations), eg:

```
len := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongWord; // or however the XML length is sent
data := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadString(len, IndyUTF16BigEndianEncoding);
```

Or:

```
data := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn('the terminator here', IndyUTF16BigEndianEncoding);
```

Comment: If i use that ReadLongWord, the server capture a list of numbers, i dont know if this is the length of all the message, or its the length of each lines.

Comment: It was an example to demonstrate a point, I did not say it would solve your problem. Without knowing more information about the actual protocol your client is using, there is no way anyone can help you solve this problem. There are multiple possible implementations, and which one to use depends on the protocol.